# Scala,type mismatch; found : (Double, Option[String]) ⇒ Double required: ((Double, Option[String]))

Tags: scala

**Code for creating the match case**

```
       object IrisSepalLengthOption {
       def sepallen(sep_len: Double,species: Option[String]):Double = species 
       match{
       case Some("Iris-setosa") => sep_len * 2
       case Some("Iris-virginica") => sep_len * 3
       case Some("Iris-versicolor") => sep_len * 4
       case _ => 0.0
     }
```

**Main method to read the data from the csv file to parse the data and to apply the above funtion**

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
    println(sepallen(4.0,Some("Iris-setosa"))) // This one works fine


    val source = Source.fromFile("E:\\MI_Dataset\\Iris.csv").getLines().drop(1).toArray
    val sepcol = source.map { line =>
      val str = line.split(",")
      val sep_len = str(1).toDouble
      val speceies = str(5).toString
      (sep_len,Option(speceies))
    }
    sepcol.take(5).foreach(println)  //This one prints the output correctly
    val p = sepcol.map(_._1)
    val s = sepcol.map(_._2)
    val result = sepcol.foreach(sepallen) //Here i am getting the mismatch error
  }

}
```

When i call the function i am getting the type mistmatch error like`(type mismatch; found : (Double, Option[String]) ⇒ Double required: ((Double, Option[String])) ⇒ ?`

How to solve this problem.If anybody clarify this it would be great helpful to me

The sample data is as follows :

- 1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
- 2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
- 3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
- 4,4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
- 5,5,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
- 64,6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
- 65,5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
  66,6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
  115,5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4,Iris-virginica
  116,6.4,3.2,5.3,2.3,Iris-virginica
  117,6.5,3,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
  118,7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,Iris-virginica

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227041/scala-lambda-function-with-map-function. There are probably many duplicates of this, don't know which should be the canonical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the subtle difference between the expected and actual types, and most importantly the parentheses :

```
type mismatch; found : (Double, Option[String]) ⇒ Double required: ((Double, Option[String])) ⇒ ?
```

The `sepallen` function, expects two arguments, a `Double` and an `Option[String]`, but the syntax  `sepcol.foreach(func)` expects `func` to be a function of a single argument : a `Tuple` (whose elements are a `Double` and an `Option[String]`)

You can fix it by exploding your tuple to feed it to `sepallen`, for example like this :

```
val result = sepcol.foreach{ case (sep_len, species) => sepallen(sep_len, species) }
```

Comment: There's also the problem that `foreach` doesn't return a `result` (at least not a meaningful result).

Comment: Instead of foreach we can use map.Its giving the desired output

Comment: Indeed, but that wasn't really in the scope of the question anyway I think, since it has a specific focus on the given exception.
@thanaselvan If this has helped/answered, don't hesitate to validate the answer

Comment: Yes the solution was really helped me and i am a new to scala and the answers will help  others also.Thanks a lot

Comment: I meant, there's a green tick box that you can click to mark your problem as solved :-) This way, the community know you don't need help anymore, and can more efficiently help others !